# How to get the JformFieldList Value by ID

Tags: joomla-3.x, jform

I created a custom field as below

```
class JFormFieldPaddyStatus extends JFormFieldList {

  protected $type = 'paddystatus';

  public function getOptions($id='') {
    $options = array();

    $options[0] = 'Raw';
    $options[1] = 'Dried';
    $options[2] = 'Grind';
    $options[3] = 'Ready';

    return $options;
  }
}
```

In the database it stores the values as 0, 1 etc... When I show the status I want to show the corresponding names instead of its value.

At the moment I show the status as below

```
<td><?php echo $row->status; ?></td>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should create a new instance of your field class and get options. Then `echo` status by `key` of `$options` `array`.

First 10 lines are needed only if you don't have classes loaded yet.

```
<?php
// Import JFormHelper if not exist
jimport('joomla.form.helper');

// Add your field path
JFormHelper::addFieldPath(JPATH_COMPONENT . '/models/fields');

// Load JFormFieldPaddyStatus class
JFormHelper::loadFieldClass('PaddyStatus');

// Classes loaded
// New instance
$PaddyStatus = new JFormFieldPaddyStatus();

// Get options
$options = $PaddyStatus->getOptions();

// Show status
<td><?php echo $options[$row->status]; ?></td>
```